# Nginx not running with no error message (ubuntu 14.04 lts)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, netstat

I am trying to start my nginx server.

When I type `$> /etc/init.d/nginx start`, I have a message appearing "Starting nginx: Ok", and then nothing happens.

When I type `sudo lsof -nP -i | grep LISTEN`, I didnt have a message with nginx(port 80)

My `error.log` file is empty. I dont have any idea. Please help me.

Nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

Here is my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file:

```
worker_processes  1; 

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}    

http {
server_names_hash_bucket_size  64;        

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;  

sendfile        on;




keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

gzip on;
gzip_http_version 1.0;
gzip_comp_level 2;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_min_length  1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

include /etc/nginx/site_enabled/*;}
```

Here is my /etc/init.d/nginx

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:   nginx
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog $named
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog $named
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: starts the nginx web server
# Description:       starts nginx using start-stop-daemon
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/usr/sbin/nginx
NAME=nginx
DESC=nginx

# Include nginx defaults if available
if [ -r /etc/default/nginx ]; then
    . /etc/default/nginx
fi

test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

. /lib/init/vars.sh
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

PID=$(awk -F'[ \t;]+' '/[^#]pid/ {print $2}' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf)
if [ -z "$PID" ]
then
    PID=/run/nginx.pid
fi

# Check if the ULIMIT is set in /etc/default/nginx
if [ -n "$ULIMIT" ]; then
    # Set the ulimits
    ulimit $ULIMIT
fi

#
# Function that starts the daemon/service
#
do_start()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been started
    #   1 if daemon was already running
    #   2 if daemon could not be started
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PID --exec $DAEMON --test > /dev/null \
        || return 1
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PID --exec $DAEMON -- \
        $DAEMON_OPTS 2>/dev/null \
        || return 2
}

test_nginx_config() {
    $DAEMON -t $DAEMON_OPTS >/dev/null 2>&1
}

#
# Function that stops the daemon/service
#
do_stop()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been stopped
    #   1 if daemon was already stopped
    #   2 if daemon could not be stopped
    #   other if a failure occurred
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --pidfile $PID --name $NAME
    RETVAL="$?"

    sleep 1
    return "$RETVAL"
}

#
# Function that sends a SIGHUP to the daemon/service
#
do_reload() {
    start-stop-daemon --stop --signal HUP --quiet --pidfile $PID --name $NAME
    return 0
}

#
# Rotate log files
#
do_rotate() {
    start-stop-daemon --stop --signal USR1 --quiet --pidfile $PID --name $NAME
    return 0
}

#
# Online upgrade nginx executable
#
# "Upgrading Executable on the Fly"
# http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html
#
do_upgrade() {
    # Return
    #   0 if nginx has been successfully upgraded
    #   1 if nginx is not running
    #   2 if the pid files were not created on time
    #   3 if the old master could not be killed
    if start-stop-daemon --stop --signal USR2 --quiet --pidfile $PID --name $NAME; then
        # Wait for both old and new master to write their pid file
        while [ ! -s "${PID}.oldbin" ] || [ ! -s "${PID}" ]; do
            cnt=`expr $cnt + 1`
            if [ $cnt -gt 10 ]; then
                return 2
            fi
            sleep 1
        done
        # Everything is ready, gracefully stop the old master
        if start-stop-daemon --stop --signal QUIT --quiet --pidfile "${PID}.oldbin" --name $NAME; then
            return 0
        else
            return 3
        fi
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
        do_start
        case "$?" in
            0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
            2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
        esac
        ;;
    stop)
        [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
        do_stop
        case "$?" in
            0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
            2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
        esac
        ;;
    restart)
        log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$NAME"

        # Check configuration before stopping nginx
        if ! test_nginx_config; then
            log_end_msg 1 # Configuration error
            exit 0
        fi

        do_stop
        case "$?" in
            0|1)
                do_start
                case "$?" in
                    0) log_end_msg 0 ;;
                    1) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Old process is still running
                    *) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Failed to start
                esac
                ;;
            *)
                # Failed to stop
                log_end_msg 1
                ;;
        esac
        ;;
    reload|force-reload)
        log_daemon_msg "Reloading $DESC configuration" "$NAME"

        # Check configuration before reload nginx
        #
        # This is not entirely correct since the on-disk nginx binary
        # may differ from the in-memory one, but that's not common.
        # We prefer to check the configuration and return an error
        # to the administrator.
        if ! test_nginx_config; then
            log_end_msg 1 # Configuration error
            exit 0
        fi

        do_reload
        log_end_msg $?
        ;;
    configtest|testconfig)
        log_daemon_msg "Testing $DESC configuration"
        test_nginx_config
        log_end_msg $?
        ;;
    status)
        status_of_proc -p $PID "$DAEMON" "$NAME" && exit 0 || exit $?
        ;;
    upgrade)
        log_daemon_msg "Upgrading binary" "$NAME"
        do_upgrade
        log_end_msg 0
        ;;
    rotate)
        log_daemon_msg "Re-opening $DESC log files" "$NAME"
        do_rotate
        log_end_msg $?
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $NAME {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status|configtest|rotate|upgrade}" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
esac

:
```

What did I miss? I have no idea what I need to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `listen`, like one of these:

```
listen 127.0.0.1:8000;
listen 127.0.0.1;
listen 8000;
listen *:8000;
listen localhost:8000;
```

reference: [Module ngx_http_core_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen)

Comment: Could be (on reflection almost certainly _is_) the reason, but there are no server blocks in the question - `include /etc/nginx/site_enabled/*`.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake. The path to the config file was not valid.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check for errors in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`.

In my case I did no add the port for ipv6. You should also do this (in case you are running nginx on a port other than 80):
`listen [::]:8000 default_server ipv6only=on;`